# RxSwift subscribe will work when initiated

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift for the first time.
It will load Post List from my server.
The first time only need to run loadPostList
but
Just by initializing the model, nextPage is called.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
class PostNetworkModel {
    var nextPage:BehaviorSubject<Void> = BehaviorSubject(value: ())
    var reFresh:BehaviorSubject<Void> = BehaviorSubject(value: ())
    var raiseError:BehaviorSubject<Void> = BehaviorSubject(value: ())
    var isLoadingComplete = false
    private var pageNo = BehaviorRelay(value: 1)
    var postList : BehaviorRelay<[Post]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [])
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    init() {
        loadPostList()
            .bind(to: postList)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        postList
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe({ ( _) in
                self.isLoadingComplete = true
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        nextPage
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] ( _) in
                print("nextPage")
                if (self?.isLoadingComplete)!{
                    self?.isLoadingComplete = false
                    self?.pageNo.accept(self!.pageNo.value + 1)
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
     }
}
```

Comment: Changed BehaviorSubject to PublishSubject

Comment: Where and how is `nextPage` used outside of this class?

Comment: @MattiaC. 
When Reach the bottom of the table view
call nextPage.onNext(())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BehaviorSubject` accepts an initial value as constructor parameter because its specification is as follows:

> Observers can subscribe to the subject to receive the last (or initial) value and all subsequent notifications.

Meaning `nextPage` will trigger a next even on subscription. You'll probably want to change all the `BehaviorSuject` to `PublishSubject` for this class

```swift
class PostNetworkModel {
    var nextPage:PublishSubject<Void> = PublishSubject()
    var reFresh:PublishSubject<Void> = PublishSubject()
    var raiseError:PublishSubject<Void> = PublishSubject()
    var isLoadingComplete = false
    private var pageNo = BehaviorRelay(value: 1)
    var postList : PublishRelay<[Post]> = PublishRelay()

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    init() {
        loadPostList()
            .bind(to: postList)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        postList
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe({ ( _) in
                self.isLoadingComplete = true
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        nextPage
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] ( _) in
                print("nextPage")
                if (self?.isLoadingComplete)!{
                    self?.isLoadingComplete = false
                    self?.pageNo.accept(self!.pageNo.value + 1)
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
     }
}
```

Note than I kept `pageNo` as a `BehaviorRelay`, as it makes sense for this observable to have an initial value.